# Multiply two columns in separate tables in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables :

- IRG_ANALYSIS : contains the total of each line
- IRG_CODES : contains the 'rate' (taux)

They are linked by a merged column

[image: LINK BETWEEN COLUMNS]

IRG_ANALYSIS :
[image]

IRG_CODES :

[image]

When I select my columns, the rate is correctly displayed ("TAUX" column) :
[image: RATE VISIBLE ON EACH LINE]

I would like to multiply "total" by "taux".

I tested this :

```
TotalIRG = CALCULATE( (SUM(IRG_ANALYSIS[Total]) * (SUM(IRG_CODES[TAUX])) /100 )
)
```

But the result is not correct : 42 insted of 21.15 (52.87 * 40/100 = 21.15)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measure is calculating the multiplication of the final two sums.

It's better to use `SUMX` and `RELATED` in this case to calculate the measure in a row level.

```
TotalIRG =
SUMX ( IRG_ANALYSIS, IRG_ANALYSIS[Total] * RELATED ( IRG_CODES[TAUX] ) / 100 )
```